# api getway spring cloud

Tags: java, spring

i have a probleme with api gatway
application.yml api-gatway
spring:
cloud:
gateway:
routes:
- id: subscriber-bc
uri: localhost:8081
predicates:
- Path=/api/canal/subscription/** #first letter must be a capital letter
application:
name: API-GATEWAY
eureka:
client:
register-with-eureka: true
fetch-registry: true
service-url:
defaultZone: http://localhost:8080/eureka/
instance:
hostname: localhost
server:
port: 8989

pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.2.2
 

com.canal.plus
api-gatway
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
api-gatway
api-gatway

<java.version>17</java.version>
<spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-actuator


org.springframework.cloud
spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc


org.springframework.cloud
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

my microservice config
eureka:
client:
service-url:
defaultZone: http://localhost:8080/eureka
server:
port: 8081
spring:
application:
name: subscriber-bc
datasource:
password: root
url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
username: postgres
jpa:
hibernate:
ddl-auto: update
properties:
hibernate:
dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
jdbc:
lob:
non_contextual_creation: true

[image]

when I call th endpoint

[image]